# Open HTML file in non-default browser

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I know how to do that manually. But, is there an option to set up one particular file to be opened always in Chrome, despite Firefox being the default browser.

What I want is to set up somehow, one HTML file on my desktop to be opened in Chrome, but the rest of the html files continue to open in Firefox, and I want this to apply always for this file, even when I move it to some other computer.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Windows is not the only one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume we are talking about the Windows OS first. Secondly, I will assume that you do not have a Chrome shortcut sitting on your desktop, if you do have a shortcut just skip to the second step otherwise continue reading on.

## Step 1: Create a Chrome Shortcut

There are many ways of doing this. Simplest one is to just search for Chrome in the Start Menu and drag the shortcut to your desktop like I have in the picture below.

[image]

## Step 2: Open the Shortcut Properties

Right click on your Chrome shortcut and click the `Properties` option, like in the image below.

[image]

## Step 3: Edit Your Shortcut's Target Value

Find the `Target` option in the `Shortcut` tab of the `Properties` window. Add the following piece of code at the end of your target statement.

> `--app=https://example.com`

Replace `https://example.com` with any website you like. In the image below the highlighted part shows where you have to edit the target value. I have made a shortcut for https://google.com.

[image]

Hope this helps!

**Note:** This is a Chrome specific trick and it will open a new window without a URL bar or a toolbar.

***Edit:** Added pictures with more description.*

Comment: Please can you explain what should I add and where? Thank you.

Comment: Hey @user3244442, I just updated my answer with more detail. Hope it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the html file then got to open with and it should display the available browsers select the one you would like to open the file with

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to make it always open in that browser. Automatically. Please reconsider my question again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set it to open (in Windows (7) ) by right-clicking on a html file, going to 'Open With' and 'Choose Default program':
[image]

on most Linux systems you should be able to right-click, go to 'Properties' and set it under 'Open With...':
[image]

---

also, in Google Chrome settings you should be able to set it as default:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I wasn't clear enough. If I set up like you show, I could open an HTML file in prefered browser one. But after that, every time users double clicks on that html file, it will be opened in default browser. Which is diferent from computer to computer.

Comment: Whoops... Under Windows I don't think this can be easily done (In Ubuntu/Fedora linux you could create a specific launcher file - probably..)